# add a class to a 2d array? Java

Tags: java, arrays, random

I need to create a map which has randomly placed trees and food. For the map i am looking to create a 2d array and then add the trees and food to the array with use of classes, is this possible?

```html
class Tree {
 char tsymbol;
}
class Food {
 char fsymbol;
 
}
```

The classes only have to have a symbol stored in them for now, which will be the icon which represents the objects on the map.

```html
public void printWorld (){
 int a;
 int b;
 char[][] map = new char[15][12];

 for (a=1; a<=15; ++a)
 {
  for (b=1; b<=12; ++b)
  {
      foodsymbol.fsymbol = 1;
      final String[] items = { };
      map[a][b] = 
    
   System.out.print(map[1][1]);
  }
  System.out.printf("\n\n");
 } 
}
```

So far i have this, ignore the comments as that was my previous work. This part is where i am trying to add the objects to the array randomly, however i am having problems accessing the variables or classes in this method.

Thanks in advance for any help:)

Comment: Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html. Notice what the first index of an array is. If you plan to add Trees and Foods to the array, do you think that char[][] is the appropriate type? What can a char array contain? Can it contain objects? Since you want to store objects in the array, what should be its type?

Comment: I just assumed char[][] would be the best, as the map would mainly be characters. Im not sure if an array is able to contain objects as im new to java and oop, and also unsure if its possible to store the object in the array and be represented by a single char?

Comment: You first need to really decide what you **want** to do. You start by saying you want to *create a 2d array and then add the trees and food to the array with use of classes*. The you say you want a char array. Either you want to use classes and store instances of those classes, or you want to store chars. It can't be both at the same time. The code you posted makes no use at all of the Tree and Food classes. So, what are these classes for?

Comment: Sorry, ill try to explain again. Overall i need to print out a text based map which a bug will eventually be added onto. I was going to store the map as a 2d array, before printing out the array i need to randomly add trees and food to the array. I was planning on making tree and food classes which will then be added into the array before printing out, but i am unsure if this is possible, which is another question.

Comment: I just would like to know, can you add objects from classes to a 2d array? and if so how would i access them in PrintWorld. The classes only store a symbol at the moment, however in the future i will expand on this. Sorry if i am making no sense still but thanks for your answer:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your particular application, you might also want to consider using an [`enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html). This is useful if all trees are identical and all food is identical. It might look something like this:

```
enum Item {
    TREE ('t'),
    FOOD ('f');

    private final char symbol;
    Item(char symbol) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }
    char getSymbol() { return symbol; }
}
class MyClass {
    public void printWorld() {
        Item[][] map = new Item[15][12];
        map[0][0] = Item.TREE;
        map[0][1] = Item.FOOD;
        System.out.print(map[0][0].getSymbol());
        System.out.print(map[0][1].getSymbol());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have tried to add this to my code however i am unsure how to call the method. I have tried the following but am getting an error.
MyClass worldnew = new MyClass();
  worldnew.printWorld();

Comment: @LogicDoe Also, how were you calling `printWorld()` before? If you were able to call it before, there's no need to change the way you call it.

Comment: I placed the class in the inside of main, so was getting an error. Solved now, thanks for you help, really appreciate it:)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can have an array of objects, and print them. To have different types of objects in the same array, they should all implement a common interface. For instance:

```
interface MapObject {
    public char getSymbol();
}
class Tree implements MapObject {
    char tsymbol = 't';

    @override
    public char getSymbol() {
        return tsymbol;
    }
}
class Food implements MapObject {
    char fsymbol = 'f';

    @override
    public char getSymbol() {
        return fsymbol;
    }
}
class MyClass {
    public void printWorld() {
        MapObject[][] map = new MapObject[15][12];
        map[0][0] = new Tree();
        map[0][1] = new Food();
        System.out.print(map[0][0].getSymbol());
        System.out.print(map[0][1].getSymbol());
    }
}
```